# Block folder with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, curl, pcre

I need to block a folder with PCRE Regular expressions. I am using Interarchy to mirror my work files via ftp but it keeps crashing on the _notes folder.

How do I block the folder _notes and all contents via PCRE RE's?

Here is a list of the standard blocks-

```
(?isx-m)
^\.         | # .files
^\(.*\)$    | # (parentheses)
^CVS$       | # CVS
^\.svn$     | # Subversion
^\.git      | # git
^_private$  | # FrontPage
^_vti_      | # FrontPage
.~$         | # Backup files
\.bak$      | # Backup files
^$
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Interarchy, but the regex `^_notes` will match any path that begins with "_notes" including "_notes" itself and any subpaths such as "_notes/a_file"